# Select elements from two tables with JOIN and UNION excluding IDs in a column

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I have 3 SQL tables like these:

```
    tbl_items
id ... name ... value ... active
1      color    red       1
2      style    modern    1
3      age      old       1
4      size     small     1

    tbl_adv_items
id ... name ... value ... active
1      texture  suave     0
2      material plastic   1

    tbl_items_classes
id ... item_id
1      1
2      3
```

I want to select all IDs from `tbl_items` and `tbl_adv_items` with a condition: exclude items from `tbl_items` if their ID exists in the `item_id` column from `tbl_items_classes`

Right now I have this query:

```
SELECT tbl_items.id FROM tbl_items 
JOIN tbl_items_classes ON tbl_items_classes.item_id <> tbl_items.id 
WHERE tbl_items.active = 1 
UNION ALL SELECT id FROM tbl_adv_items WHERE active = 1
```

which gives me all the items, including those with their ID in `item_id`. ID *1* and *3* from `tbl_items` should not be returned. I guess I need a `JOIN` here but I can't make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`EXCEPT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_items WHERE tbl_items.active = 1 

UNION ALL 

SELECT id FROM tbl_adv_items WHERE active = 1

EXCEPT 

SELECT item_id FROM tbl_items_classes
```

This will have the effect of excluding all `item_id` values contained in table `tbl_items_classes`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8073f/1)

**EDIT:**

If you also want to know the origin of the `id` returned by the query (something not clearly stated in the OP), then you can use the following query:

```
(SELECT id,  0 AS origin_table FROM tbl_items WHERE tbl_items.active = 1 

UNION ALL 

SELECT id,  1 AS origin_table FROM tbl_adv_items WHERE active = 1)

EXCEPT 

(SELECT item_id, 0 AS origin_table FROM tbl_items_classes

UNION ALL

SELECT item_id, 1 AS origin_table FROM tbl_items_classes)
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work pretty well. A problem I have right now is that I want to know which ID comes from which table, so apart from id, I specify the table like this: `SELECT id, 0 as origin_table FROM tbl_items WHERE tbl_items.active = 1 UNION ALL SELECT id, 1 as origin_table FROM tbl_adv_items WHERE active = 1 EXCEPT SELECT item_id FROM tbl_items_classes` but I get an error (205 - the number of expressions is not equal)

Answer (score 1):

For performance reason use classic `LEFT JOIN`:

**[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369471)**

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id , 'tbl_items' AS origin
  FROM tbl_items 
  WHERE active = 1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, 'tbl_adv_items'  AS origin
  FROM tbl_adv_items 
  WHERE active = 1
)
SELECT c.id, c.origin
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN tbl_items_classes cl
  ON c.id = cl.item_id
WHERE cl.item_id IS NULL;
```

Left second case.

[image]
Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: @ali Could you compare execution plans EXCEPT vs LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make joins between tables and put a condition to filter records. Try this:

```
select * from tbl_items tblA
inner join tbl_adv_items tblB on tblA.id = tblB.Id
left outer join tbl_items_classes tblC on tblA.id = tblC.item_Id
where tblC.Id is null -- this check will exclude desired items
```